# Repeating local notification removes previous pending local notifications

Tags: ios, swift, localnotification, unnotificationrequest, unnotificationtrigger

I want to send local notification after every 30 minutes. I have implemented repeating local notification but it removes the preceding local notifications. The scenario is as explained : 
My client wants to get night alerts. He wants that when he wakes up in the morning he can check all the notification alerts at once.

Here is the code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound], completionHandler: {didAllow,error in  })
    return true
}
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Hello"
    content.subtitle = "I am your local notification"
    content.body = "Yippppiiiieee...."
    content.badge = 1
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 60, repeats: true)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "testing", content: content, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you shouldn't use the same identifier as it removes already scheduled ones

```
 let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "testing", content: content, trigger: trigger)
```

second you have to insert different TimeInterval

```
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 60, repeats: true)
```

//

```
(1...10).forEach {

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Hello \($0)"
    content.subtitle = "I am your local notification \($0)"
    content.body = "Yippppiiiieee.... \($0)"
    content.badge = 1
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval:TimeInterval($0*1800), repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "testing\($0)", content: content, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)

}
```

Comment: How can I set a different time interval when I want to get notification after every 30 minutes

Comment: for Unique identifier you can generate random string and for 30 min time interval, you can add 30 min in current time.

Comment: Use this to repeat every 30 minutes **let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1800, repeats: true)**

Comment: The above line will repeat the same notification every 30 minutes , if you need different body/content , then insert it inside a for-loop and set different identifier , with repeating set to false

Comment: when your first notification will fire, didreceivelocalnotification function will execute,where you can write code to fire notification using UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1800, repeats: true).

Comment: I have a bunch of different notifications to fire after every 30 minutes

Comment: Yes this edit is working fine. But how would I define the count for loop? Here it is static i.e 10

Answer (score 0):

Previous pending notification is canceled, because you create a new one with the same `identifier`. As per [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationrequest/1649633-requestwithidentifier?language=objc)

> If you provide a unique identifier, the system creates a new notification.
>
> If the identifier matches a previously delivered notification, the system alerts the user again, replaces the old notification with the new one, and places the new notification at the top of the list.
>
> If the identifier matches a pending request, **the new request replaces the pending request.**

The solution is to always create `UNNotificationRequest` with a new identifier

```
var notificationCount = 0

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // (...)
    notificationCount += 1
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "testing\(notificationCount)", content: content, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
}
```

Comment: After 3 notifications again it has started removing the previous ones.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the same identifier. It will override the previous notification.

Now you would ask, how will I identify which notification was tapped If I generate a random string every time?

So let's say, you have this identifier named "coffeeTimeNotificationID". Just append a timestamp value (`[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]]`) to this string. Now your string would look like this: "`coffeeTimeNotificationID1232134314`".

Whenever user taps on this notification, just search for "`coffeeTimeNotificationID`", in the identifier string. If you find it, you'll know what type of notification was tapped.